# Listing pending and ongoing studies?

Tags: publications, research-process, thesis, writing, cv

I am applying to a professional post graduate program and they are looking for publications or research experience. I have a research paper, that has been approved for publication, but not yet published.. should I list this under "Publications section"?

I also have 1 ongoing research (finished collecting data, commenced with manuscript writing) and 1 research that I have sent for approval, but not yet approved. How can I correctly list these in my CV?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The first paper you can list in publications, but mark it as "to appear" unless you know the date of publication provided by the publisher. Use that date instead, assuming the near future, if you have it.

For the second, put a section on the CV labelled "Work In Progress" and list it there with a descriptive name.  Having work in progress is a good thing to have.